# Distance function of the Ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, analysis

Let $\epsilon(a,b)$ denote the Ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. the set $\lbrace (x,y): \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\rbrace $.

Is there an explicit way to compute $f_{a,b}(x)=\operatorname{dist}(\epsilon(a,b),x)$ for points $x$ inside the ellipse boundaries?

For the circle ($a=b=1$) one for example has $f(x)=r - \Vert x \Vert$.

P.s. I want to show that $f_{a,b}(x)=\operatorname{dist}(\epsilon(a,b),x)$ has a unique maximum point and it is equal to $0$. Given this statement is true, maybe there is an easier way to see it than computing the function explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to show that $f_{a,b}(x, y) = \operatorname{dist}(\epsilon(a, b), (x, y))$ has a unique maximum point and it is equal to $(0, 0)$.

(I've taken the liberty of writing points as ordered pairs in your question statement.)

Without loss of generality, say $0 < b < a$. For each $x_{0}$ with $-a < x_{0} < a$, there exists a unique $0 < y \leq b$ such that $(x_{0}, \pm y)$ lie on $\epsilon(a, b)$. These points are separated by a distance of $2y \leq 2b$, with equality if and only if $x_{0} = 0$.

If $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ is inside the ellipse, then $|y_{0} - y| + |y_{0} + y| = 2y \leq 2b$. It follows at once that
$$
f_{a, b}(x_{0}, y_{0}) = \min(|y_{0} - y|, |y_{0} + y|) \leq b,
$$
with equality if and only if $(x_{0}, y_{0}) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: Do you mean $$
f_{a, b}(x_{0}, y_{0}) \leq  \min(|y_{0} - y|, |y_{0} + y|) \leq b,
$$
instead of $=$? (Of course this does not change your argument.)

Comment: Oops, yes, that first equality should read $\leq$.

Answer (score 4):

The ellipse can be parametrized as
$$x=a\cos\phi\\
y=b\sin\phi$$
Then, the distance from a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $p=(x_0,y_0)$, to any point to the ellipse is
$$d^2(p,\epsilon)=(x_0-a\cos\phi)^2+(y_0-a\sin\phi)^2$$
The distance can be minimize (or maximize) by taking the derivative with respect to the angle, $\phi$, finding
$$(a^2+b^2)\sin\phi\cos\phi=ax_0\sin\phi-by_0\cos\phi$$
This equation will provide the maximum and minimum distance from the point to the boundary of the ellipse

**note**
This equation can be transformed into a fourth order equation, by using the changes of variable $\cos\phi=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ and $\sin\phi=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: Can you please explain, why the equality is true? The coordinate change you mentioned is not an isometry.

Comment: You are right, the distances are not preserved under this change of variable. However, if the minimum distance between the ellipse $\epsilon$ and the point $x\in\epsilon$ (let me know if I have understood well your question) is zero, it has to be zero in both system of coordinates

Comment: I am interested in the function $\operatorname{dist}(\varepsilon(a,b),x)$ on the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where x lies inside of the boundary of the ellipse. In particular if $x$ is not on $\varepsilon(a,b)$ the function will have a non-zero value.

Comment: @Near please, check out the corrected answer. I am worried there is no general analytic solution to the problem. However, it should be possible to demonstrate that the equation has two solutions, related to the maximum and the minimum distances to the ellipse.